# kubernetes service without selector not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-ec2

i need to access my elasticsearch server that runs on EC2 server outside the K8S cluster. so, i setup service without selector as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors). but, when i try to test it with:

1. curl to service -> response timeout
2. curl to direct IP -> response OK

i think i already followed all the instruction that doc says. so, what do i miss?.any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Elasticsearch service without selector:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9200
---
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name:
    elasticsearch-endpointslice # by convention, use the name of the Service
    # as a prefix for the name of the EndpointSlice
  labels:
    # You should set the "kubernetes.io/service-name" label.
    # Set its value to match the name of the Service
    kubernetes.io/service-name: elasticsearch
addressType: IPv4
ports:
  - port: 9200
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - "172.31.28.11"
```

debug pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: debug4
  labels:
    app: debug4
spec:
  containers:
    - name: debug4
      image: clue/httpie
      command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

[image]